# using summarize within a mutate rather than a left_join

Tags: r, tidyverse

I was wondering if this workflow could be improved upon:

```
dummy <- tibble(
  x = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)),
  value = c(1:15)
)

dummy %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(rowsum = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(s = sum(rowsum)) %>%
  left_join((dummy %>% pivot_longer(-x)), by = "x")
```

Ideally I'd rather not use a left_join which calls the original dataframe - anyone have a better suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `replace` the elements other than the first to `NA` and get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dummy %>% 
   pivot_longer(-x) %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   mutate(rowsum = sum(value), 
           s = replace(rowsum, row_number() != 1, NA)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(s = sum(s, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 15 x 5
#    x     name  value rowsum     s
#   <chr> <chr> <int>  <int> <int>
# 1 A     value     1     15   120
# 2 A     value     2     15   120
# 3 A     value     3     15   120
# 4 A     value     4     15   120
# 5 A     value     5     15   120
# 6 B     value     6     40   120
# 7 B     value     7     40   120
# 8 B     value     8     40   120
# 9 B     value     9     40   120
#10 B     value    10     40   120
#11 C     value    11     65   120
#12 C     value    12     65   120
#13 C     value    13     65   120
#14 C     value    14     65   120
#15 C     value    15     65   120
```

---

Or without using `pivot_longer`

```
dummy %>% 
    mutate(s = sum(value)) %>% 
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(rowsum = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what you're going for with the `name` column, but this replicates your output without using `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(row_sum = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(s = sum(unique(row_sum)),
         name = "value")
select(x, row_sum, s, name, value) # only to reorder the columns as you had them
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   x     row_sum     s name  value
   <chr>   <int> <int> <chr> <int>
 1 A          15   120 value     1
 2 A          15   120 value     2
 3 A          15   120 value     3
 4 A          15   120 value     4
 5 A          15   120 value     5
 6 B          40   120 value     6
 7 B          40   120 value     7
 8 B          40   120 value     8
 9 B          40   120 value     9
10 B          40   120 value    10
11 C          65   120 value    11
12 C          65   120 value    12
13 C          65   120 value    13
14 C          65   120 value    14
15 C          65   120 value    15
```

Comment: Ah sorry that name column was an error - thank you!